# How to do Inline Linear-Gradient in Nuxt / Vue

Tags: css, vue.js, background-image, linear-gradients, nuxt.js

I'm searching for a way to apply a linear-gradient over top of my inline background image. I've tried to just right a CSS style but the class is being placed underneath the image.

```
<div class="header__bkgd" v-bind:style="{'background-image': 'url(' + require('~/assets/images/dist_bkgd.jpg') + ')'}"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Gradients can be added on top of image with this css **background** style:

```
background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 23, 32, 0.5) 100%, rgba(255, 32, 32, 0.5) 100%),
url('/static/bg.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: How can I import this function? When I paste code like this I got a white background as this function seems not to exist.

Comment: Thank you! In my case, I had other property ` background-colour: ` - linear-gradient doesn't work with it, a white area appears instead of the chose colours.